# Please clarify me thats wrong in my selection sort code

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

In this method only one element is getting sorted rest of the elements are are not sorted.

Please help me to find where the actual problem is

```
private static int[] selectSort(int[] arr) {

    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int min_Ele = i;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] <= arr[min_Ele]) {
                min_Ele = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != min_Ele) {
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i = min_Ele];
            arr[min_Ele] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Hint: wrong for example: your naming. Dont call something "arr", call it "numbers to sort" for example. And dont call it min_ele (double bad using "_" !) ... call it "indexOfSmallestNumber" for example. And hint: you solve such puzzles ... by using print statements; or by running small examples in the debugger. You dont need us to do that!

Comment: i am fresh to programming..so i need some help

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that your inner loop should start from `i+1` and not from `1`.

```
public static int[] selectSort(int[] arr) {

    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int min_Ele = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] <= arr[min_Ele]) {
                min_Ele = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != min_Ele){
            //swap
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i = min_Ele];
            arr[min_Ele] = tmp;
        }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
private static int[] selectSort(int[] arr) {

    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        int min_Ele = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] <= arr[min_Ele]) {
                min_Ele = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != min_Ele) {
          int tmp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[min_Ele];
          arr[min_Ele] = tmp;
        }
     }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: That is not how you write good answers. You shouldn't just drop code, you explain the problem in the original source code; and you tell how you fixed it. Sorry, but your question is of the same low quality than the original question! You even have the same "mis-formatting"!